# Cancel a saga when an action is dispatched with redux-saga

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-saga

I start a timer for a stopwatch React component when a START action is dispatched:

```
import 'babel-polyfill'
import { call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import { delay, takeEvery, takeLatest } from 'redux-saga'
import { tick, START, TICK, STOP } from './actions'

const ONE_SECOND = 1000

export function * timerTickWorkerSaga (getState) {
  yield call(delay, ONE_SECOND)
  yield put(tick())
}

export default function * timerTickSaga () {
  yield* takeEvery([START, TICK], timerTickWorkerSaga)
  yield* takeLatest(STOP, cancel(timerTickWorkerSaga))
}
/*
  The saga should start when either a START or a TICK is dispatched
  The saga should stop running when a stop is dispatched
*/
```

I have trouble stopping the saga when the `STOP` action is dispatched from my component. I have tried using `cancel` and `cancelled` effects from within my worker saga:

```
if(yield(take(STOP)) {
  yield cancel(timerTickWorkerSaga)
}
```

as well as the approach in the first code block where I try and stop the saga from the watching service.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looks like a few things are going on here:

1. The `cancel` side effect [takes a `Task` object as its argument](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/docs/api/README.md#canceltask). What you're passing into it in the code above is just the `GeneratorFunction` that creates the saga/Generator object. For a great intro to generators and how they work, check out [this article](https://davidwalsh.name/es6-generators).
2. You're using `yield*` before the `takeEvery` and `takeLatest` generators. Using `yield*` will [spread the whole sequence](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/docs/advanced/SequencingSagas.md). So you can think of it like this: that it's filling in the line

   `yield* takeEvery([START, TICK], timerTickWorkerSaga)`

   with

   ```
   while (true) {
       const action = yield take([START, TICK])
       yield fork(timeTickWorkerSaga, action)
   }
   ```

   And I don't think this is what you're going for, because I believe this will end up blocking the second line of your `timerTickSaga`. Instead you probably want:

   ```
   yield fork(takeEvery, [START, TICK], timerTickWorkerSaga)
   ```

   This forks off the `takeEvery` effect so it doesn't block the next line.
3. The second argument you're passing into `takeLatest` is just an object - a [CANCEL effect object](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/docs/api/README.md#canceltask). The second argument to `takeLatest` should actually be a `GeneratorFunction`, which will be run when an action matching the `STOP` pattern is dispatched to the Redux store. So that should really be a saga function. You want this to cancel the `fork(takeEvery, [START, TICK], timerTickWorkerSaga)` task so that future `START` and `TICK` actions will not cause the `timerTickWorkerSaga` to run. You can achieve this by having the saga run a `CANCEL` effect with the `Task` object that resulted from the `fork(takeEvery...` effect. We can the `Task` object as an [additional argument](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/docs/api/README.md#takelatestpattern-saga-args) to the `takeLatest` saga. So we end up with something along the lines of:

   ```
   export default function * timerTickSaga () {
       const workerTask = yield fork(takeEvery, [START, TICK], timerTickWorkerSaga)
       yield fork(takeLatest, STOP, cancelWorkerSaga, workerTask)
   }

   function* cancelWorkerSaga (task) {
       yield cancel(task)
   }
   ```

For additional reference check out the [task cancellation example](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/docs/advanced/TaskCancellation.md) in the redux-saga docs. If you look in the `main` saga there, you'll see how the `fork` effect yields a `Task` object/descriptor that is used further down when yielding the `cancel` effect.

Comment: As you might have suspected, I have been neglecting ES6 generators, thanks you for the answer and the useful resources.

Answer (score 19):

Redux-Saga has a method for this now, it's called race `race`. It will run 2 tasks, but when one finishes, it will automatically cancel the other.

- https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/RacingEffects.html
- watchStartTickBackgroundSaga is always running
- Every time there's a start or tick, start a race between timerTickWorkerSaga and listening for the next STOP action.
- When one of those tasks finishes, the other task is cancelled
  this is the behavior of race.
- The names "task" and "cancel" inside of race do not matter, they just help readability of the code

---

```
export function* watchStartTickBackgroundSaga() {
  yield takeEvery([START, TICK], function* (...args) {
    yield race({
      task: call(timerTickWorkerSaga, ...args),
      cancel: take(STOP)
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Hi Cory, Your's the only that solution worked for me in my case. I have two questions:
1) When I use the solution provided by @Marc, the saga gets cancelled, but it just won't listen again to the same action. Why is that?
2) In your solution, what is the use of (...args) parameter? It works even without providing those?

Comment: `...args` will save all arguments of the `function*` and save them as an array in a variable called `args`. Using them in `call(timerTickWorkerSaga, ...args)` will then pass all of those arguments into `timerTickWorkerSaga`. In redux-saga the argument would be the action that was caught in `takeEvery` - See https://jsfiddle.net/0pg1zy45/

Comment: Marc's solution is not listening again, because you're actually cancelling the `takeEvery` effect. My solution is nested within the `takeEvery`, and the actual `timerTickWorkerSaga` task is cancelled rather than the `takeEvery`. So my solution will start a race on every `START/TICK` and cancel on `STOP`, but Marc's will run `takeEvery START/TICK` and is cancelled on a `STOP`.

Comment: @CoryDanielson Man...that's brilliant. Thanks for taking the time out and explaining things. That fiddle helped me a lot in understanding that `args`.

Comment: For forked tasks that's the best option for sure.

Answer (score 9):

The answer from rayd is very correct but a bit superfluous in the way that takeEvery and takeLatest internally are doing a fork.
You can see the explanation [here](https://yelouafi.github.io/redux-saga/docs/advanced/Concurrency.html):

So the code should be:

```
export default function* timerTickSaga() {
    const workerTask = yield takeEvery([START, TICK], timerTickWorkerSaga);
    yield takeLatest(STOP, cancelWorkerSaga, workerTask);
}

function* cancelWorkerSaga(task) {
    yield cancel(task);
}
```